# call a specific function only once on an event which may be called many times?

Tags: jquery

I have a live click function that needs to do certian things always but one thing must only execute on the first click, after that, it needs to be disabled.

```
$('.theImage').live("click", function(){ 
            // The commands within the if statement must only happen on the first click.
    if (!chkHeightOnceOnly){
        var containerHeight = $(this).children(".postInfo").height();
        $(this).children(".postInfo").height(containerHeight - 2);
        var chkHeightOnceOnly = true; 
    }
            // other commands which need to fire on every click go here
});
```

So currently every-time i click on the div, it's subtracting a further 2px. It only needs to subtract 2px the first time.

EDIT - This is for many instances of .theImage, which are coming in via ajax, hence the need for .live()

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Those "jQuery —" pretexts in the titles may seem repetitive as they are mentioned in the tags, but they are very helpful for stack overflow and for searchers in google. #justsayin

Comment: They are completely redundant. Tags are used in searches: in fact, the primary tag is automatically rendered in the page title, because that is how Stack Overflow is designed to work. Let Stack Overflow handle the SEO, by using tags and titles properly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store the flag in the HTML tag itself.

```
$('.theImage').live("click", function(){ 
    // The commands within the if statement must only happen on the first click.
    if ($(this).attr('data-once')!='already' ){
        var containerHeight = $(this).children(".postInfo").height();
        $(this).children(".postInfo").height(containerHeight - 2);

        $(this).attr('data-once', 'already');
    }
    // other commands which need to fire on every click go here
});
```

Comment: what does that mean Tomalak? Have to say this one works, it's unbreakable! Thanks Moe. So is this the best way to go about it? What does everyone else think?

Comment: The best way is using jQuery's in-built data storage mechanism, but this is certainly a viable -- and more or less equivalent -- approach. You should still remove all those duplicated `$(this)` calls for sure.

Comment: True i only just learned about that trick in another q  posted earlier. Cheers for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this memory property to be on a per-node basis, use each node's [jQuery `data` property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$('.theImage').live('click', function() {
    var $obj = $(this);

    // Allow handler to run only once per element
    if ($obj.data('chkHeightOnceOnly')) {
       return;
    }
    $obj.data('chkHeightOnceOnly', true);

    // Interesting stuff
    var containerHeight = $obj.children('.postInfo').height();
    $obj.children('.postInfo').height(containerHeight - 2);
});
```

Comment: Whoops... it's doing something odd again. It used to be that if i clicked outside .theImage clicked back in, etc, it would always go back to it's initial state. Now i'm getting the overlays doubling up. I'm using id adds and removes via click on the html tag, that seems to have stopped working with this addition.

Comment: You ca see what i mean if you click a pair of divs a few times here http://syndex.me (it did work before the new code btw)

Comment: @RGBK: I cannot parse your problem statement. Are you _sure_ that this specific code change caused this? I doubt it. Please verify by rolling it back.

Comment: It definitely was, I've clicked these divs for the last two weeks, it never did that, and i copied the code correctly. But it's a cool trick for me to know anyhow so it was helpful, thank you.

Comment: $.data() seems interesting, never knew it before.

Comment: @RGBK: `$obj.data` does not magically cause multiple divs to appear on your page. Maybe the "problem" introduced is that, as desired, your handler no longer fires multiple times for the same element? Some other part of your code was relying on the original broken behaviour. To solve _this_ question, prove the validity of my solution _in isolation_.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `chkHeightOnceOnly` outside the function's scope. Currently, the declaration is within the function's scope. This way, the value gets reset each time.

```
var chkHeightOnceOnly = false;

$('.theImage').live('click', function() { 
    if (!chkHeightOnceOnly) {
        var containerHeight = $(this).children('.postInfo').height();
        $(this).children('.postInfo').height(containerHeight - 2);

        chkHeightOnceOnly = true; 
    }
});
```

Comment: I suspect he wants it per-element.

Comment: Yeah that would normally work but it's per element, thats where my conundrum lies.

Comment: Use `$.data`. Refer **[Tomalak Geret'kal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/tomalak-geretkal)**'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924324/call-a-specific-function-only-once-on-an-event-which-may-be-called-many-times/7924355#7924355).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it by using a combination of `.live()` and a special class that is just for the one-time triggering.  Upon the first click, you remove the special class so the object will no longer match the .live() selector specification.

```
$(".fireOnce").live("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("fireOnce");
    // do your other stuff here
});
```

And you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KU6wZ/.